# Spring Boot Security - Ant Matcher doesn't work

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, roles

I am trying to get familiar with spring boot security, my API is a simple GET/POST to 127.0.0.1:8080/employee/
with a simple autoconfiguration like this.

```java
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Configuration
    protected static class ApplicationSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

        @Override
        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                    .withUser("user1").password("{noop}user1").authorities("USER").and()
                    .withUser("user2").password("{noop}user2").authorities("USER").and()
                    .withUser("admin").password("{noop}admin").authorities("ADMIN");
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.antMatcher("/employee/**").authorizeRequests().anyRequest().hasRole("ADMIN");
        }
    }
}
```

This always gives me 403 Forbidden.
Have tried this:-
antMatcher("/employee*"), works but for any user. Can I get some help in understanding how this pattern works, I just need to restrict "/employee" or "/employee/" or "/employee/1" to Admin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current configuration will only restrict any paths under `employee` e.g. `employee/1` but not `/employee`. Additionally you are not doing anything with the `employee` matcher as you go back to `authorizeRequests`, then configure `anyRequest` has a role `ADMIN`

To restrict `employee` and any path underneath it to `ADMIN`.

```
     http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/employee**", "/employee/**").hasRole("ADMIN").httpBasic();
```

Using `**` will capture directories in path.

See

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/AntPathMatcher.html

and

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/web/util/matcher/AntPathRequestMatcher.html

> Using a pattern value of /** or ** is treated as a universal match, which will match any request. Patterns which end with /** (and have no other wildcards) are optimized by using a substring match — a pattern of /aaa/** will match /aaa, /aaa/ and any sub-directories, such as /aaa/bbb/ccc.

I would also recommend testing your security configuration via the `@WebMvcTest` slice test

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-integration-tests

From the above a simple example would be,

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(SecuredController.class)
public class SecuredControllerWebMvcIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    // ... other methods

    @WithMockUser(roles= {"admin"})
    @Test
    public void givenAuthRequestOnPrivateService_shouldSucceedWith200() throws Exception {
        mvc.perform(get("/employee/1").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
          .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
    //Repeated for other Paths
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, but I guess there is something still wrong in my understanding, Because your solution works but allows non admins also.. I guess I'll have to read the entire doc of spring..

Comment: @sagar additional change to the config to enable http basic. I did make a basic app that works to your specification and appears to work as you'd like

Comment: A few corrections made it work,  disabling csrf helped it behave correctly. `csrf().disable`.
My dumb mistake, was giving _authorities_ to the auth and checking for _roles_ in the httpSecurity.. 

Darren, yes, the http basic with Postman. And thank you very much for the `WebMvcTest` advice!!